# how to remove controls from embedded video?

Tags: html, embed

Is it actually impossible to remove the UI controls from this embedded video?
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_objectmplayer

```
<param showcontrols="false"> 
<param uiMode="invisible">
```

...showcontrols="false"...

does not hide the controls - contrary to natural english meaning of "show controls"

EDIT:  --THE FOLLOWING WORKS & IS CROSS-BROWSER (until IE10)...
EDIT2: --BUT THE FOLLOWING ALSO SEEMS TO CAUSE NEVER-ENDING-SENDRESPONSE-STATUS WORKER PROCESSES (SEE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790199/iis7-5-wmv-requests-cause-many-workerprocesses-in-never-ending-sendresponse-stat)

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <object id="MediaPlayer" style="height:100%" classid="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">

        <param name="filename" value="3d.wmv" />
        <param name="Showcontrols" value="false" />
        <param name="autoStart" value="True" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <object id="mediaplayer" type="application/x-ms-wmp" data="3d.wmv" width="100%" height="80%">
        <param name="src" value="3d.wmv" valuetype="ref" type="3d.wmv">

        <param name="autoStart" value="1">
        <param name="ShowControls" value="0">
        <param name="Showcontrols" value="false" />
        <param name="autoStart" value="True" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="0">
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0">
        <param name="playcount" value="10">
        <param name="autoRewind" value="1">
        <param name="displaysize" value="0">
        <param name="stretchtofit" value="1">
        <param name="enableContextMenu" value="0">
        <param name="uiMode" value="none">
        <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="3d.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
    </object> 
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your W3Schools example code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<object width="100%" height="100%"
type="video/x-ms-asf" url="3d.wmv" data="3d.wmv"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<param name="url" value="3d.wmv">
<param name="filename" value="3d.wmv">
<param name="autostart" value="1">
<param name="uiMode" value="full">
<param name="autosize" value="1">
<param name="playcount" value="1">                              
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="3d.wmv" width="100%" height="100%" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"></embed>
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Change

```
<embed... showcontrols="true"...
```

to

```
<embed... showcontrols="false"...
```

Comment: thanks, but if you try it (at least in chrome), it doesnt work..ie controls are still shown.

Comment: keep in mind, you cannot completely hide controls permanently. only make them temporarily hidden

Comment: @user2282496 take a look at this page -> http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed-examples.html   you can see that the showcontrols="true" have controls showing all the time.

Comment: unfortunately, its exactly the opposite effect that I am after.  I want to Hide/remove the controls all the time.

Comment: @user2282496 as i said then, it's not possible.   if you were to be able to do that, noone would be able to pause the window from playing, ergo, spam the user with all kinds of unwanted videos, and they have no control over it.