# How to hide the controller of <embed>?

Tags: html, video, embed, mp4

Thanks for reading or answering my question... ^3^
when I use **embed** tag to embed a mp4 file in the HTML,  the view of the video shows the controller when begin to play and when playing is over.  Could anyone tell me how to hide the controller?

Thanks again.

Comment: Could you add some of your working code for us please?

Comment: This problem is resolved, but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

video tag has support that

here is good sample.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

```
<video width="400" controls> // <- you have to remove 'contorls'
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216593/how-to-remove-controls-from-embedded-video

Comment: Thanks,  `video` tag affects.. Thanks a lot.   ^3^